# Result vs raise in F# async?

Tags: f#, async-await

It seems like there are two ways to return errors in an `async` workflow: `raise` and `Result`.

```
let willFailRaise = async {
  return raise <| new Exception("oh no!")
}

let willFailResult = async {
  return Result.Error "oh no!"
}
```

For the caller, the handling is a bit different:

```
async {
  try 
    let! x = willFailRaise
    // ...
  with error -> 
    System.Console.WriteLine(error)
}

async {
  let! maybeX = willFailResult
  match maybeX with
  | Result.Ok x -> 
    // ...
  | Result.Error error -> 
    System.Console.WriteLine(error)
}
```

My questions are:

- What are the advantages / disadvantages of each approach?
- Which approach is more idiomatic F#?

Comment: This is a great question and I encourage everyone to chime in. Personally, I prefer `Result`. In fact I handle all exceptions by making them into a `Result`. That is because I am not writing .Net libraries only web sites and code to be used within F#. On the other hand combining monads like Async and Result (and possibly others like Reader, Writer, State, Free) it is not easy in F#. There are several implementations out there for AsyncResult Computation Expressions. Lately I have been experimenting with the Eff monad that can handle all of them, but it is still very experimental for me.

Answer (score 10):

It depends on what kind of error we are talking about. Basically there are three kinds:

- Domain errors (e.g. user provided invalid data, user with this email is already registered, etc.)
- Infrastructure errors (e.g you can't connect to another microservice or DB)
- Panics (e.g. `NullReferenceException`or `StackOverflowException` etc.), which are caused by programmers' mistakes.

While both approaches can get the job done, usually your concern should be to make your code as self-documented and easy-to-read as possible. Which means the following:

- **Domain errors:** definitely go for `Result`. Those "errors" are expected, they are part of your workflow. Using `Result` reflects your business rules in function's signature, which is very useful.
- **Infrastructure failures:** it depends. If you have microservices, then probably those failures are expected and maybe it would be more convenient to use `Result`. If not -- go for exceptions.
- **Panics:** definitely `Exception`. First of all, you can't cover **everything** with `Result`, you gonna need global exception filter either way. Second thing -- if you try to cover all possible panics - code becomes a nasty disaster extremely fast, that will kill the whole point of using `Result` for domain errors.

So really this has nothing to do with `Async` or C# interop, it's about code readability and maintainability.
As for C# iterop -- don't worry, `Result` has all the methods to help, like `IsError` and so on. But you can always add an extension method:

`[<AutoOpen>]
module Utils =
    type Result<'Ok, 'Error> with
        member this.Value =
           match this with
           | Ok v -> v
           | Error e -> Exception(e.ToString()) |> raise`

Answer (score 7):

This is one of the many aspects of F# programming that suffers from the mind-split at the core of the language and its community.

On one hand you have "F# the .NET Framework language" where exceptions are the mechanism for handling errors, on the other - "F# the functional programming language" that borrows its idioms from the Haskell side of the world. This is where `Result` (also known as `Either`) comes from.

The answer to the question "which one is idiomatic" will change depending who you ask and what they have seen, but my experience has taught me that when in doubt, [you're better off using exceptions](https://eiriktsarpalis.wordpress.com/2017/02/19/youre-better-off-using-exceptions/). `Result` type has its uses in moderation, but result-heavy programming style easily gets out of hand, and once that happens it's not a pretty sight.

Comment: Interesting article, but can't the limitations of `Result` mentioned there be overcome by using discrimated unions and computation expressions? (except for C# interop of course, but that isn't always relavent)

Comment: The message in that article is a bit extreme in my opinion. Everything depends on the context. For instance it criticizes catching all exceptions and turning them into Results. I do exactly that, and I think it is absolutely necessary when building a user interface to control the user experience. OTOH, If you are building a Rest-API you do not need to catch all exceptions because the infrastructure already does it for you. If you are building a library then you should not return Result unless failures are normal and usually expected to be handled by the caller, as exceptions are slower.

Comment: @sdgfsdh: No, they can't, they're inherent to the idea of using types for handling errors in a runtime that allows for exceptions. You can use syntax sugar to smooth out some of the bumps, but you're hardly overcoming any of the problems mentioned in the blog post. As for computation expressions, result builder is great when all you care is the happy path, but becomes painful the moment you actually want to "handle" your "exceptions".

Comment: @AMieres: This is why I said the answer will change depending who you ask and what they have seen ;) A major problem with using types for handling errors in real life codebases is that you are dealing with code that is written by many people with different levels of experience over long periods of time, and you have to trust everyone involved to have just the right amount of discipline necessary to prevent exceptions from surfacing. Too often you end up with a house of cards, and lack of proper stack traces means that you spend hours divining what went wrong when it ultimately collapses ;)

Comment: @scrwtp I see what you are saying. A proper base functionality and discipline is necessary before you can use Result types in large projects. That is why context is important, each situation is different.

Comment: @AMieres After experimenting, I have found that unifying the error types adds rather a lot of friction. Normally, a workflow error is the _union_ of the errors types of its sub-workflows. Have you overcome this, or is this a serious limitation of the `Async<Result<'T, 'E>>` approach?

Comment: Maybe we should open another question to discuss it more properly as it would muddy this post. Why don't you open a specific question and share you current code as an example of the issue you have found?

Comment: @AMieres Good idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53536450/merging-discriminated-unions-in-f

Answer (score 5):

> Raise

Advantages

- Better .NET interop as throwing exceptions is fairly common in .NET
- Can create custom Exceptions
- Easier to get the stack trace as it's right there
- You probably have to deal with exceptions from library code anyways in most standard async operations such as reading from a webpage
- Works with older versions of F#

Disadvantages:

- If you aren't aware of it potentially throwing an exception, you might not know to catch the exception. This could result in runtime explosions

> Result

Advantages

- Any caller of the async function will have to deal with the error, so runtime explosions should be avoided
- Can use [railway oriented programming](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/rop/) [style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/results), which can make your code quite clean

Disadvantages

- Only available in F# 4.1 or later
- Difficult for non-F# languages to use it
- The API for Result is not comprehensive.

  - There are only the functions `bind`, `map`, and `mapError`
  - Some functions that would be nice to have:

    - `bimap : ('TSuccess -> 'a) -> ('TError -> 'e) -> Result<'TSuccess,'TError> -> Result<'a, 'e>`
    - `fold : ('TSuccess -> 'T) -> ('TError -> 'T) -> Result<'TSuccess, 'TError> -> 'T`
    - isOk

Comment: There's nothing inherent to `async` in the use of `Result`, so I don't think that really counts against it - pre-4.1, you could simply use a custom discriminated union. Could you elaborate on the non-comprehensive API for Result?

Comment: @shambulator I listed some of the functions that would have been nice to have