# "Merging" Discriminated Unions in F#?

Tags: error-handling, f#

Following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53506325/result-vs-raise-in-f-async), I am having an issue combining differently typed `Result` types together.

*(what follows is a contrived example, not real code)*

Suppose I have a function that reads a file:

```
type ReadFileError = 
| FileNotFound of string

let readFile (path : string) : Result<string, ReadFileError> =
  // --- 8< ---
```

And a function that parses it somehow:

```
type JsonParseError = 
| InvalidStructure of string

let parseJson (content : string) : Result<Json, JsonParseError> = 
  // --- 8< ---
```

Now I can combine these to create a function that reads and parses a file:

```
type ReadJsonError = 
| ReadFileError of ReadFileError
| JsonParseError of JsonParseError

let readJson (path : string) : Result<Json, ReadJsonError> = 
  match path |> readFile with
  | Ok content -> 
    match content |> parseJson with 
    | Ok json -> Ok json
    | Error e -> Error (ReadJsonError.JsonParseError e)
  | Error e -> Error (ReadJsonError.ReadFileError e)
```

As you can see, unifying the error types is rather awkward. I need to define a new union-type and wrap the `Error` side properly. This is not something you have to worry about with an exception based approach, since throw is open-ended with regard to types.

Is it possible to make the `Result` style convenient when combining errors of different types?

Answer (score 3):

Short and easy answer first. I'll come back later for a longer answer.

If you are building a monolithic application the suggestion is to create just one Error type for the whole application:

```
type AllErrors = 
| FileNotFound of string
| InvalidJsonStructure of string
| OtherErrors ...
```

That will give you one nice place where all errors are defined and you can create a unified `printError` and other error-handling functions.

Sometimes that is not possible, for instance if your code is modular and each module has its own ErrorType then you have two options, still create a unique type and map to it or create a nested, composed type like you did. It is your decision. In both cases you use `Result.mapError`

Syntactically there are many ways to do this. To avoid the nested `match`s you use `Result.bind` and `Result.mapError`

```
let readJson (path : string) : Result<Json, ReadJsonError> = 
    readFile path 
    |> Result.mapError ReadFileError
    |> Result.bind (fun content ->
    parseJson content 
    |> Result.mapError JsonParseError
    )
```

If you had a `result` Computation Expression:

```
type Builder() =
    member inline this.Return          x       = Ok  x
    member inline this.ReturnFrom      x       =     (x:Result<_,_>)
    member        this.Bind           (w , r ) = Result.bind  r w
    member inline this.Zero           ()       = Ok ()
let result = Builder()
```

then it would look like this:

```
let readJson (path : string) : Result<Json, ReadJsonError> = result {
    let! content = readFile  path    |> Result.mapError ReadFileError
    return!        parseJson content |> Result.mapError JsonParseError
}
```

with operators:

```
let (>>= ) vr f = Result.bind     f vr
let (|>>.) vr f = Result.mapError f vr
```

it could be this:

```
let readJson (path : string) : Result<Json, ReadJsonError> = 
    readFile path     |>>. ReadFileError
    >>= fun content ->
    parseJson content |>>. JsonParseError
```

or this:

```
let readJson (path : string) : Result<Json, ReadJsonError> = 
    path 
    |>   readFile  
    |>>. ReadFileError
    >>= fun content ->
    content 
    |>   parseJson 
    |>>. JsonParseError
```

or even this:

```
let readJson (path : string) : Result<Json, ReadJsonError> = 
    path           |>
    readFile       |>>. 
    ReadFileError  >>= 
    fun content    ->
    content        |>   
    parseJson      |>>. 
    JsonParseError
```

Ok, this last one is just for fun. I am not advocating you code like this.

also you could simply create unified version of your functions:

```
let readFileU = readFile  >> Result.mapError ReadFileError
let readJsonU = parseJson >> Result.mapError JsonParseError
```

and bind them with the Kleisli operator:

```
let (>=>) f g p = f p |> Result.bind g

let readJson = readFileU >=> readJsonU
```

Answer (score 3):

Combining the error types is a problem with `Result` that I only realized when trying it out.

With exceptions this is "solved" with having all exceptions inherit a base class. So one similar approach could be `type R<'T> = Result<'T, exn>`

However, I find that unappealing and usually fall into a pattern where I define my own Result type that allows aggregated failures of a homogeneous type.

A bit like this

```
type BadResult = Message of string | Exception of exn
type BadTree = Leaf of BadResult | Fork of BadTree*BadTree
type R<'T> = Good of 'T | Bad of BadTree
```

Another approach could be to combine `Result` failures using `Choice`. Not sure one would end up into an especially appealing place with this.

```
let bind (t : Result<'T, 'TE>) (uf  'T -> Result<'U, 'UE>) : Result<'U, Choice<'TE, 'TU>> = ...
```

This probably don't help you at all but perhaps it spawns a few ideas on how to proceed?